# Randomized button sometimes overlap each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

On the OnClick method of one of my Button, I am randomizing its position on the screen...
It works perfect but when I use 2 or 3 buttons to randomize their position, they sometimes overlap each other e.g. One button halfly overlaps the other button...

here is the method for Random Position of button -

```
private void moveButton()
    {
        if(!canMove){ return; }

        runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                        Point size = new Point();
                        display.getSize(size);
                        int width = size.x;
                        int height = size.y;

                        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                        Random r = new Random();

                        int startX = width/2;
                        int startY = height/2;

                        if(myscores==0){
                            button.setX(startX);
                            button.setY(startY);
                        }

                        else {

                            int x = r.nextInt(width - 210);
                            int y = r.nextInt(height - 200);

                            button.setX(x);
                            button.setY(y);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }
```

Any help would be highly Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the button overlaps the other button and move it again if it does:

```
int x = r.nextInt(width - 210);
int y = r.nextInt(height - 200);

if (x < other.getX() + other.getWidth()
     && x + button.getWidth() > other.getX()
     && y < other.getY() + other.getHeight()
     && y + button.getHeight() > other.getY()) {

   moveButton();
   return;
}

button.setX(x);
button.setY(y);
```

Comment: here the 'other' means the another button right? :)

Comment: Thank You So Much :) Works like a Charm :D